# Website based on Laravel with Angular component

Tags: angular, laravel

I need to create regular website (no [SPA](https://google.com/search?q=single+page+application)!) with [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) PHP Framework and with [Angular](https://angular.io/) components on this site.

Eg.:
[image]

Is it possible? If yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it's a real pain in the a**. I did one with Java Spring last month. Basically you have to bootstrap each element after manually checking if the element is exists

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, DOCUMENT }  from '@angular/platform-browser';

// Add all components to this array
const components: any[] = [
  //normal components goes here
    LoginFormComponent
];

// Bootstrap components
const mainComponents: any[] = [
  AngularComponent
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    .
    .
    .
  ],
  providers: [...],
  declarations: components,
  entryComponents: mainComponents
})
export class AppModule { 
  private browser_document: any;

  // this bootstraps each main component
  ngDoBootstrap(app: any) {
    for(let component of mainComponents) {
      if (this.browser_document.getElementsByTagName(component.selector).length > 0) app.bootstrap(component);
    }
  }

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) {
    this.browser_document = document;
  }
}
```

**angular.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'angular-component',
    templateUrl: './valuation.requests.view.component.html'
})
export class AngularComponent {
    static selector: String = 'angular-component'; // this is important
}
```

**something.html**

```html
<angular-component></angular-component>
```

Basically you have to bootstrap every sub component after checking if it's exists on the DOM

PS: main components needs to add both `components` and `mainComponents` arrays

Answer (score 0):

I had to do to same thing lately and the solution I found is not that complicated.

I have two projects. The tree as below:

- angular-app
- laravel-app

**1. Create a symlink in the Laravel’s public folder to your angular dist.**

```
cd laravel-app/public
ln -s ../../angular-app/dist/angular-app/ angular
```

**2. Set up your Laravel .env** like this :

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
APP_URL_ANGULAR=http://localhost:4200
```

**3. Set up your Laravel routes:**

```
Route::get('/angular-app/{route}', function() {
  return view('my-page');
})
->name('laravel.index')
->where('route', '[a-z-\/0-9]+');
```

Laravel will return its view no matter which Angular route is called, as long as the URL contains the “angular-app” prefix. The Laravel page will include the Angular application. The Angular routing will handle the rest.

**4. Add this code to your Blade template:**

```
<app-root></app-root> 
@if (getenv('APP_ENV') != 'local') 
    <script src="{{ getenv('APP_URL') }}/angular/runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script> 
    <script src="{{ getenv('APP_URL') }}/angular/runtime-es5.js" nomodule defer></script> 
    <script src="{{ getenv('APP_URL') }}/angular/polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script> 
    <script src="{{ getenv('APP_URL') }}/angular/polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script> 
    <script src="{{ getenv('APP_URL') }}/angular/styles-es2015.js" type="module"></script> 
    <script src="{{ getenv('APP_URL') }}/angular/styles-es5.js" nomodule defer></script> 
    <script src="{{ getenv('APP_URL') }}/angular/vendor-es2015.js" type="module"></script> 
    <script src="{{ getenv('APP_URL') }}/angular/vendor-es5.js" nomodule defer></script> 
    <script src="{{ getenv('APP_URL') }}/angular/main-es2015.js" type="module"></script> 
    <script src="{{ getenv('APP_URL') }}/angular/main-es5.js" nomodule defer></script> 
@else 
    <script src="{{ getenv('APP_URL_ANGULAR') }}/runtime.js?t={{ time() }}" type="module"></script> 
    <script src="{{ getenv('APP_URL_ANGULAR') }}/polyfills.js?t={{ time() }}" type="module"></script> 
    <script src="{{ getenv('APP_URL_ANGULAR') }}/styles.js?t={{ time() }}" type="module"></script> 
    <script src="{{ getenv('APP_URL_ANGULAR') }}/vendor.js?t={{ time() }}" type="module"></script> 
    <script src="{{ getenv('APP_URL_ANGULAR') }}/main.js?t={{ time() }}" type="module"></script> 
@endif
```

Do not forget:

```
<base href="/">
```

...between the head tags.

In local environment, we will include all the files generated by ng serve. This will allow us to rebuild our Angular application on file changes. In any other environment, we will target the build of our Angular application using our symbolic link.

**5. Test the apps**

First, update your angular.json:

```
"serve": { 
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server", 
  "options": { 
    "browserTarget": "angular-app:build", 
    "publicHost": "http://localhost:4200" 
  }, 
  […] 
},
```

Then serve your apps:

```
php artisan serve –port=8000
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --port 4200
```

As, like you, I did not find a lot of information about this topic, I wrote an article with a few more details:
https://medium.com/@z3c33/how-to-integrate-an-angular-application-in-laravel-9f6021b573e4